# Helping without being asked, is this legal?

Tags: munchkin

My brother and his friend were playing Munchkin Legends, and my brother helped him when it wasn't asked of or needed. He then stated that he was in the battle, and he tried to run away, even though he wasn't the one fighting or needed. He then played the Lemming Parade card so his friend had to run away. His friend and I thought that that was against the rules because my brother wasn't the one who had to run away. Is it against the rules?

Comment: Well, it may be against the rules, but it certainly isn't against the spirit

Answer (score 15):

**No**, a player may not foist help upon you.

The rules state "you may ask any other player to help you" at which point the player may accept or deny the request. There is no "involuntary" help.

[image: rules snippet]

In addition, in your specific case, since help was not needed, even requesting help is not allowed, according to the official Munchkin FAQ:

> **Q. Am I allowed to ask for help if I am currently winning the fight? The rules say I can ask for help if I'm losing, but nothing about if I'm winning.**
>
> A. That's because if you're winning, you don't need help, and a true munchkin would never ask for help he doesn't need. Unless a card says otherwise (and a couple do, for their own weird reasons), you may not ask for help if you are winning a combat.

**Source:** [Official FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/)

Comment: I think you meant to say since help was not needed instead of since help was needed.

Comment: I think that technically, there are cards that force other players to accept your help. But the base rules are indeed that you have to be asked to help.

Comment: Being able to force your help would make the elf race overpowered, since you would be able to gain levels freely on other people's turns.

Answer (score -4):

Please keep in mind the pan-ultimate rule of Munchkin (which should be adopted for every game): The owner decides any unclear ruling issues.

Also, your brother couldn't have played the card, since he wasn't the one running away.

Comment: There does not appear to be any unclear ruling issues as the rules specifically cover this question.

Comment: There was dissent amon the players, so the ruling was not clear (at least to one of them).

Comment: Well, we can Munckin-ize that sentiment and allow the owner of the game to declare any rules that suit him. If anyone argues with him, he defaults to being right!